# Tailwind CSS ignoring the padding of my element

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm building a comment/reply system using MPTT and I'm trying to use indentation to clearly show which comments are replies and on which level those replies are.

I am using the `comment.level` attribute to determine the padding value, so a comment.level of 0 would be the parent (therefore no padding), a reply to that parent comment would have a comment.level of 1 (therefore padding of 1), a reply to that reply would have a comment.level of 2 (therefore padding of 2). This would then create that indentation of `pl-0` for the parent comment, `pl-1` for the first reply and `pl-2` for that second reply.

```
{% load mptt_tags %}
        {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
            {% for comment in comments %}
                {% if comment.level > 0 and comment.tree_id == tree_id %}
                    <div class="pl-{{ comment.level }} mt-2">
                        <div class="relative grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 p-4 mb-4 border rounded-lg bg-white shadow-lg">
                            <div class="relative flex gap-4">
                                <div class="flex flex-col w-full">
                                    <div class="flex flex-row justify-between">
                                        {% if not comment.deleted %}
                                            <p class="relative text-xl whitespace-nowrap truncate overflow-hidden">{{ comment.level }}</p>
                                        {% else %}
                                            <p class="relative text-xl whitespace-nowrap truncate overflow-hidden">[deleted]</p>
                                        {% endif %}
                                        <a class="text-gray-500 text-xl" href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                        <p class="text-gray-400 text-sm">{{ comment.date_added }}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {% if not comment.deleted %}
                                <p class="-mt-4 text-gray-500">{{ comment.body }}</p>
                            {% else %}
                                <p class="-mt-4 text-gray-500">[deleted]</p>
                            {% endif %}
                            <div class="relative">
                                {% if user == comment.author and not comment.deleted %}
                                    <button hx-delete="{% url 'posts:delete_comment' comment.id post %}" hx-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete your comment?" class="-mt-4 text-gray-500">delete</button>
                                {% endif %}
                                <button hx-get="{% url 'posts:comment_reply' id=comment.id pk=post %}" hx-swap="afterend" class="mr-auto -mt-4 text-gray-500">reply</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
```

The problem I'm having is that the padding is being ignored, the padding is coming through correctly in the DOM as I can see my replies have padding like `pl-3`. I'm assuming it's because the parent div isn't allowing the element to apply padding but I can't work it out.

When the "see replies..." button is clicked in the below code (near the bottom) it triggers an AJAX call and loads the above bit of code.

```
{% if comments %}
        {% load mptt_tags %}
            {% recursetree comments %}
                <div class="relative grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 p-4 mb-4 border rounded-lg bg-white shadow-lg">
                    <div class="relative flex gap-4">
                        <div class="flex flex-col w-full">
                            <div class="flex flex-row justify-between">
                                {% if not node.deleted %}
                                    <p class="relative text-xl whitespace-nowrap truncate overflow-hidden">{{ node.level }}</p>
                                {% else %}
                                    <p class="relative text-xl whitespace-nowrap truncate overflow-hidden">[deleted]</p>
                                {% endif %}
                                <a class="text-gray-500 text-xl" href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></a>
                            </div>
                                <p class="text-gray-400 text-sm">{{ node.date_added }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% if not node.deleted %}
                        <p class="-mt-4 text-gray-500">{{ node.body }}</p>
                    {% else %}
                        <p class="-mt-4 text-gray-500">[deleted]</p>
                    {% endif %}
                    <div class="relative">
                        {% if user == node.author and not node.deleted %}
                            <button hx-delete="{% url 'posts:delete_comment' node.id post.pk %}" hx-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete your comment?" class="-mt-4 text-gray-500">delete</button>
                        {% endif %}
                        <button hx-get="{% url 'posts:comment_reply' id=node.id pk=post.pk %}" hx-swap="afterend" class="mr-auto -mt-4 text-gray-500">reply</button>
                        <button onclick="this.disabled = true" hx-get="{% url 'posts:load_replies' id=node.tree_id pk=post.pk %}" hx-swap="afterend" class="absolute right-0 text-gray-500">see replies...</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endrecursetree %}
    {% else %}
        <p>No comments</p>
{% endif %}
```

Appreciate it might be hard to picture, hopefully this image helps, you can see the replies to the post don't indent inwards despite them having incremental padding.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quick trial:** If you hard-code `pl-2` at the part where you have `pl-{{ comment.level }}`, does it work?

I suspect your issue is related to using dynamic class names. As per [official docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names), Tailwind only scans for readily available class names in your code. So `pl-{{ comment.level }}` would never have any generated CSS.

You can try safelisting all possible padding values in your Tailwind Config like this:

```
  safelist: [
    'pl-1',
    'pl-2',
    'pl-3',
    // more as you deem fit..
  ]
```

More on [safelisting](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I didn't know about dynamic class names being an issue. Reading the safelisting link you shared I should avoid going down that route, however, I've got no idea how I'd implement the indentation I'm after without it!

Comment: Yeah, I once got stuck with something like this too. I hope I saved you hours of banging your head on the wall :)

Comment: You did, I'm glad I only wasted 30 minutes trying to fix it on my own